# CloudFormation Init command fails

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Cannot work out for the life of me what is matter with the `DevSSHKeys` command is:

https://gist.github.com/alexlatchford/d3911e5a8139e71fdf2707f02428c6b7

It invokes the command, shown by [this log line](https://gist.github.com/alexlatchford/d3911e5a8139e71fdf2707f02428c6b7#file-cfn-init-log-L17). This code was working a few weeks ago, I go to try SSHing into a machine that has auto-scaled and now it doesn't seem to work. Even if I try to re-invoke the command manually using:

```
/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack <stack name> --resource EcsInstanceLc --region us-west-2
```

I get the same response.. Anyone see anything inherently wrong with this template?

Alex

Comment: The relevant parts of your code should be in the question, not in external files links.

The problem here is that "test" runs first and always fails, thus the "command" section is never run. The "test" is intended to be used to determine if the command needs to be run, not to check if it ran successfully.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDolberg that's the problem! Just didn't check the docs properly, obviously must have been some other keys in previously. Will try to remember to put the question in properly next time. If you want the accepted answer, write up a response and I'll accept

Comment: It's your test that is failing, not the command.  Right?

Comment: Yep all fixed now